# node.js modify file data stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filestream, fs

I need to copy one large data file to another destination with some modifications. `fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile` are very slow. I need to read line by line, modify and write to new file. I found something like this:

```
fs.stat(sourceFile, function(err, stat){
    var filesize = stat.size;

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(sourceFile);

    // HERE I want do some modifications with bytes

    readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destFile));
})
```

But how to make modifications ? I tried to get data with `data` event

```
readStream.on('data', function(buffer){
    var str = strToBytes(buffer);
    str.replace('hello', '');
    // How to write ???
});
```

but don't understand how to write it to file:

Comment: [`through2`](https://github.com/rvagg/through2) can help you. The first example code pretty much shows exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `transform` stream and use pipes like this:

```
fs.createReadStream('input/file.txt')
     .pipe(new YourTransformStream())
     .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output/file.txt'))
```

Then it's just a matter of [implementing the transform stream as in this doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream)

You can also make this easier for you using [`scramjet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) like this:

```
fs.createReadStream('input/file.txt')
     .pipe(new StringStream('utf-8'))
     .split('\n')                                          // split every line
     .map(async (line) => await makeYourChangesTo(line))   // update the lines
     .join('\n')                                           // join again
     .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output/file.txt'))
```

Which I suppose is easier than doing that manually.

Comment: how to do this synchronously, as in how do i know when this has completed and then return back to the calling function?

Comment: Well, you don't need to do it synchronously and with streams it is not the point. You can use async/await and then just return a promise that resolves on `onFinished`.

If you want, create a new question regarding this and post it here - I'll answer in more detail. :)