# nodejs - replace a string everywhere in a large file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have some huge files which are difficult to read in memory. I need to read each line and then replace double quotes if found and edit the same file. Right now, I am reading the file line by line, storing in an array and overwriting the same file. But, that's giving memory issue for big files. Any pointers ? 
Here is my present implementation :

```
var allData = fs.readFileSync(fileName, { encoding: 'utf8' }).toString().split("\n");
var finalString = "";
for (i in allData) {

    allData[i] = allData[i].replace(/"/g, '""');
    finalString = finalString.concat(allData[i]);
    finalString = finalString.concat("\n");

}
fs.writeFileSync(fileName, finalString);
```

Is there a way to edit by reading one line at a time and changing that in the file?

I have seen the similar question with scramjet, but that gives an error and is not compatible with all nodejs versions : [node.js modify file data stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775480/node-js-modify-file-data-stream)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js modify file data stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775480/node-js-modify-file-data-stream)

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, yes a variation of it might help, but i need it to be the same file, i am not able to do it for the same file - and putting it in a temp file and then renaming it is not working synchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through a lot of answers, this worked for me which took care of the required synchronous and asynchronous behaviour, large file and keeping the name same.

```
function format_file(fileName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (fs.existsSync(fileName)) {
            var fields = fileName.split('/');
            var tempFile = "";
            var arrayLength = fields.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength - 1; i++) {
                tempFile = tempFile + fields[i] + "/";
                
            }
            tempFile = tempFile + "tempFile" + fields[arrayLength - 1];
            console.log("tempfile name is : " + tempFile + " actualFileName is :" + fileName);
            var processStream = new ProcessStream();
            fs.createReadStream(fileName, { bufferSize: 128 * 4096 })
                .pipe(processStream)
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tempFile)).on('finish', function() { // finished
                    fs.renameSync(tempFile, fileName);
                    console.log('done encrypting');
                    resolve('done');
                });
        } else {
            reject('path not found')
        }
    });
}
```