# NestJS: Problems with returning modified data from StreamableFile.getStream().addListener('data', (data) => {...})

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am using the StreamableFile to read a JSON file in my service. In my
`data.getStream().addListener('data', (data) => { ... }`, I am reading the data stream. However, I am unable to return my `dataValues` variable. I guess it is because of the wrong scope. I've tried to use a global variable but due to the asynchronicity, it didn't work as intended.

How would you return the variable?

**data-manipulation.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable, StreamableFile } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class DataManipulationService {
  normalizeData(data: StreamableFile) {
    return data.getStream().addListener('data', (data) => {
      const modifiedData = JSON.parse(data);
      try {
        const slicedata = modifiedData['jsonData'].data;

        const dataValue = {
          used: (() => {
            let values = [];
            slicedata.forEach((element) => {
              values.push(element[1]);
            });

            // normalize data
            let normalizedValues = [];
            const maxValue = Math.max(...values);
            const minValues = Math.min(...values);
            values.forEach((element) => {
              normalizedValues.push(element / maxValue);
            });
            return normalizedValues;
          })(),
        };
        return dataValue; <----  Problem HERE
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Not able to process data', error);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**finding.controller.ts**

```js
 @Get('mydata')
  testingWithChromium() {
    const data = this.visualization.loadJsonData(
      'src/data/Findingscontroller/mydata.json',
    );
    return this.dataManipulation.normalizeData(data);
  }
```

Comment: you can't modify data like that. you have to do it in pipe. see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49654862/5058682) helps.

Comment: thanks @AmitKumar, it definitely helps to know what you can't do. I'll try it out following your link